# Is there any way to run 16-bit apps on android?

Tags: android, terminal, 16-bit, dosbox, termux

I'm trying to port an old executable file as an app for Android.

So the user should feel that he's using an app, but without knowing that's it was previously a 16-bit executable...

Is there any way to achieve it[using DOSBox or Termux]?

Even some guidance or a ready-made android project(dosbox) which just needs a config file would do.

Comment: Android is usually powered by an ARM cpu. Therefore it can not execute x86 code (no matter if it is 16/32 or 64 bit). Therefore you need an emulator like `quemu`.

Comment: With the help of an emulator, just as how dosbox does it. There are android apps that run dosbox so as to emulate 16-bit executable, com and batch files which have somehow mounted the phones's storage. Is there any open-source project to easily achieve it? So it can be easy for anyone to primarily focus on the porting the executable.

Comment: There's a unofficial port of DOS that has done it. In fact there's an android app on Playstore. Can someone else please help me out?